# ForEach retornando apenas um objeto na lista

Tags: java, loop, jsp

Tenho uma pagina JSP e nela eu quero que saia uma lista. Pra isso, criei um método `listarTodos()` dentro da classe do DAO e settei os campos para mostrar os dados do objeto, ficando assim o código:

```
</div>

        <%  
            ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
            List<Produto> produtos = produtoDAO.listarTodos();
        %>
            <table class="table table-striped table-inverse">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Produto</th>
                        <th>Tipo de Produto</th>
                        <th>Quantidade</th>
                        <th>Preço em R$</th>
                        <th>Tipo de Negociação</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%for(Produto produto : produtos){ %>
                    <tr>                        
                        <td><%=produto.getIdProduto()%></td>
                        <td><%=produto.getNomeProduto()%></td>
                        <td><%=produto.getTipoProduto()%></td>
                        <td><%=produto.getQtdProduto()%></td>
                        <td><%=produto.getPreco()%></td>
                        <td><%=produto.getTipoNegociacao()%></td>
                        <td>Editar</td>
                        <td><a href="prodcontroller.do?acao=excluir&input_codigo=<%=produto.getIdProduto()%>">Excluir</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <%} %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

O problema é que ele ta listando o numero de registros certos, porém está populando todos os objetos "produto" com apenas uma linha do banco. Então, se eu tenho lá N registros, esses N registros iriam popular o objeto com o mesmo dado.

Exemplo: id: 123; produto:banana: tipo:fruta; qnt:6 ; preço=1.0 ; tipo de negociação: venda. <~~~~ isso Nos 14 objetos criados.

Segue o código do método:

```
public List<Produto> listarTodos() {
        ConexaoBD conexao = new ConexaoBD();
        conexao.conecta();
        List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
        Produto produto = new Produto();

        try {
            Statement st = conexao.conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(LISTAR_TUDO);
            while(rs.next()) {          
                produto.setIdProduto(rs.getInt("id_produto"));
                produto.setNomeProduto(rs.getString("ds_tipo_produto"));
                produto.setNomeProduto(rs.getString("nm_produto"));
                produto.setQtdProduto(rs.getInt("nr_quantidade"));
                produto.setPreco(rs.getDouble("vl_preco"));
                produto.setTipoNegociacao(rs.getString("ds_tipo_negociacao"));
                produtos.add(produto);

            }
            rs.close();


        } 
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return produtos;

    }
```

Vocês conseguem ver onde estou errando?

Comment: Como está o SQL nessa variável LISTAR_TUDO ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM produto

Comment: Aparentemente era para funcionar ... você tem um construtor referente ao objeto Produto? ... Porque não tenta `produtos.add(new Produto(rs.getInt("id_produto"),rs.getString("ds_tipo_produto")) );`

Comment: Isso dentro do While do listar todos?

Comment: while(rs.next()) {  
 produtos.add( new Produto(rs.getInt("id_produto"),
             rs.getString("ds_tipo_produto")
      ));

Comment: Rapaz, eu acho q era isso mesmo meu problema o Construtor ta fora do While... tto travado desde cedo nisso hahaha, vou testar aqui e ja falo.

Comment: Beleza, tenta ai

Comment: hahahaha, foi !!! que inocencia a minha eu apenas coloquei o construtor dentro do while. Valeu pela luz ai Bruno!!!

Comment: Haha fico feliz em ter ajudo, classifique a resposta como resolvida! Até a proxima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente alterar o While do Listar Todos, criando uma nova instancia do Objeto a cada chamada do result

```
while(rs.next())          
   produtos.add( new Produto (rs.getInt("id_produto"),
                              rs.getString("ds_tipo_produto")) );
```